# How best to handle the large amount of type errors when converting a Javascript project to Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

The situation comes up when converting a Javascript project to Typescript that there is an enormous amount of Type errors in the project. Looking for techniques to handle this enormous tech debt on a mature project where going back and writing all the types is an impossible task to do all at once.

To be clear, this is not a question about how to migrate a project technically, but how to handle the enormous load of the migration while being able to use the type checking on new features. For example, one idea I had was to take a sort of snapshot of the errors at the beginning, and then suppress those errors, but show new errors from new features.

Comment: I'm sure this is a dupe, but until it gets marked, here's the corresponding handbook page: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/migrating-from-javascript.html

Comment: Another relevant page: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/intro-to-js-ts.html

Comment: @jsejcksn - Yeah, I see a lot of articles on the technical details of migrating various project to Typescript mostly like a 'how to', but I wasn't able to find one on this particular facet of migration.

Comment: "*there is an enormous amount of Type errors in the project*" - what kind of errors are you talking about? By default, just running `tsc` on the javascript code should infer most things to be `any`, and ignore them for typechecking purposes.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73992099/how-best-to-handle-the-large-amount-of-type-errors-when-converting-a-javascript?noredirect=1#comment130647901_73992099) @Dobler I searched more and still couldn't find a canonical duplicate, so I'll provide some essential guidance from the handbook in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`@ts-check`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/intro-to-js-ts.html#ts-check) and `@ts-nocheck` directives to control whether or not the compiler will typecheck individual modules.

> You can skip checking some files by adding a `// @ts-nocheck` comment to files.

There are also directives for suppressing compiler errors on individual lines:

> TypeScript may offer you errors which you disagree with, in those cases you can ignore errors on specific lines by adding `// @ts-ignore` or `// @ts-expect-error` on the preceding line.

---

For more information, there's an entire section of the TypeScript handbook dedicated to this topic: [Migrating from JavaScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/migrating-from-javascript.html).